# Combining Variables into a function

Tags: javascript, variables

Im looking to combine variables into a text string.

```
$(function(){
var txt = $("#titleDisplay");
$("#para1").html(txt);
});
```

Above is what i have so far, Id like to take that and add see below

```
$(function(){
var txt = '<img src=\"' $("#titleDisplay") + $("#titleDisplay") + $("#titleDisplay") '\">';
$("#para1").html(txt);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you explain what you are attempting to do?

Comment: Note `$("#titleDisplay")` will not render a string of the element's contents but  

"[object Object]"

Comment: I think you need +'s in between your strings and variables.
    var txt = '<img src=\"' + $("#titleDisplay") + $("#titleDisplay") + $("#titleDisplay") + '\">';

Comment: What nodetype does #titleDisplay point to?

Comment: @James: It can only be an element node. Do you mean what kind of element?

Comment: Sure,the page im building is a json/jquery image gallery, Im trying to build out a pinterest button, so im reusing values found in the base js file. This is what i should end up with >                                                                 <a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=XX PAGE URL XX&media=XX MEDIA URL XX&description=XX DESCRIPTION XX" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal"><img border="0" src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" /></a>

Comment: Definitely need more information.  What is your expected result?  Can we see the html?

Comment: and finally on my html page i would render with                        <span id="para1"></span>

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing the `+` between the string and the variables. That's all you need.

I'm not even going to ask why you are trying to get

```
<img src="[object Object][object Object][object Object]">
```